# Getting a selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException even with WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm running into  TimeoutException even after adding a wait time for WebDriver. I'm searching up SKUs one by one using data from a Pandas dataframe generated from an Excel spreadsheet.

My code never reaches the line where it sends the keys.

```
search_bar = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[contains(@class='searchbox-inner-searchtext')])")))
search_bar.send_keys(sku)
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    cross_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//*[@class='MuiSvgIcon-root'])[2]")))
    cross_click.click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('No Product Found.')
    pass
```

Comment: The `TimeoutException` is BECAUSE of the WebDriverWait. It's timing out because it can't find the element you are looking for or it's not reached the state you are expecting... present, visible, clickable, etc. The most likely cause is that the locator is not correct or your element is in an IFRAME. Have you tested your locator in the browser using `$$()` or `$x()` to ensure that it's correct? Have you looked to see if your element is in an IFRAME?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find it using the FULL XPATH inspect option as well as your provided class name. I am sure there are other ways; I typically go with whatever is easiest unless being asked to test access a very specific way.

```
search_bar = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input")))
search_bar = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "searchbox-inner-searchtext")))
```

Answer (score 1):

`contains()` has a different syntax, the value has to be separated from the attribute by a comma.

The correct syntax is `//div[contains(@class, 'searchbox-inner-searchtext')]` for XPATH, or shorter `div[class*='searchbox-inner-searchtext']` with CSS Selector.